# Request uri in array

Tags: php, arrays, uri

With a URI such as `/test/test/test`, I would like a way to create an array from `$__SERVER['request_uri']` such as this:

```
[0] => '/' [1] => /test/ [2] => /test/test/ [3] => /test/test/test/
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A quick an dirty script I just created for you:

```
<?
        $path = "/test/test2/test3";
        $arr = explode("/", $path);

        $arraynew = array();

        $i=0;
        foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
                if (($k==0) && ($v=="")) {
                        $arraynew[$i] = "/";
                        $i++;
                        continue;
                }
                if ($i == 1) {
                        $arraynew[$i] = $arraynew[$i-1] . $v;
                } else {
                        $arraynew[$i] = $arraynew[$i-1] . "/" . $v;
                }
                $i++;
        }

        print_r($arraynew);
?>
```

Or this one that's more clean and simple and adds "/" at the end:

```
<?
        $path = "/test/test2/test3";
        $arr = explode("/", $path);

        $arraynew = array();

        $i=0;
        foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
                $i > 0 ? $arraynew[] = $arraynew[$i-1] . $v . "/" : $arraynew[] = "/";

                $i++;
        }

        print_r($arraynew);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up the [`dirname()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php).

It gives you the parent directory of any given filename or directory name.

In your case, simply use it repeatedly (in a loop) to get each successive parent folder name.